# Is Lync chat, or Persistent Chat a viable alternative to email based alerts?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, logging, archive, lync-2013

I'm dealing with an envrionment that mostly uses email for alerting.  The issue I have is that all emails must be journaled by policy.

In addition, each email is replicated via SMTP using SMTP redundancy, and then again with DAG redundancy.  The messages themselves are tiny (5K), but are so numerous that email archiving/stubbing/shortcutting provide no space, size, or other savings.

Today I discovered a mailbox that had hundreds of thousands of alerts totaling 10GB.

I'm looking for a more efficient mechanism to deliver alerts, other than email.

- Is Lync a viable mechanism for this? What about persistent chat?

My thought is that developers will call the "send message" in the following link to post to a chat group

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933148(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: +1 for interesting idea, but I wonder how it would work for after-hours support.

Comment: Lync works regardless of hours...???

Answer (score 1):

You could, the real problem isn't getting the message via lync, but about having an effective audit trail for when on call developer doug ignores the IM.  He could always claim he didn't get the IM, but SMTP has complete delivery headers, showing that the mail was in the mailbox he was supposed to be checking.  If that's not important than yes its possible, the lync client is available on a variety of platforms.